# Typescript generic interface function

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I have a little problem with my generic interface function. I guess I watched too long on the same point... can someone please show me what Iam doing wrong?

Interface:

```
export interface Compareable<T>
{
    equals(compareable:T):boolean;
}
```

function:

```
function isInCompareableArray<T>(compareable:Compareable<T>, arr:Array<Compareable<T>>) : boolean
{
  for(let i of arr)
  {
    if (compareable.equals(i)) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

call:

```
let dateRef:DateRef //DateRef implements Compareable<DateRef>
let arr:Array<DateRef>

isInCompareableArray<DateRef>(dateRef, arr);
```

Error:

```
ERROR in function ... if (compareable.equals(i)) return true; 
...: Argument of type 'Compareable<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

Iam bit lost here. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
function isInCompareableArray<T>(compareable: Compareable<T>, arr: Array<T>): boolean {
    for (let i of arr) {
        if (compareable.equals(i)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Where the array is of type `Array<T>` (or simply `T[]`) instead of `Array<Compareable<T>>`.

Comment: :D Thanks! Just saw it by my own... guess I need a break ^^

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... shame on me :) I lost the scope.

This works:

function:

```
export function isInCompareableArray<T>(compareable:Compareable<T>, arr:Array<T>) : boolean ...
```